# jquery BlockUI - Transparent loading image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a image I want to make spin as transparent when my screen is blocked.  By default there is a white box as the message CSS.  Not sure how to achieve this.

source: view-source:http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos

This section here creates a white box around the image.

```
$.blockUI({  message: '<h1><img src="./images/loading.gif" /></h1>'
```

If I comment this section of the source code out the whole image disappears.

```
css: {
  padding:         0,
  margin:          0,
  width:           '30%',
  top:             '40%',
  left:            '35%',
  textAlign:       'center',
  color:           '#000',
  border:          '3px solid #aaa',
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  cursor:          'wait'
},
```

Comment: `backgroundColor:'#fff'` …?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
css: {
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  border: '0'
},
```

example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/johnboker/ft3vwn2f/

Comment: I'm glad I could help.