# Jquery BlockUI Does not block the whole page only block message area

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, blockui, jquery-blockui

BlockUI does not block the whole page. It just blocks the message area, the rest of the page can continue as if nothing had happened.

```
  $.blockUI({
                message: '<img src="/assets/media/loading3.gif" />',
                css: {border: '0px solid #FFFFFF', cursor: 'wait', backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' },
                overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', opacity: 0.0, cursor: 'wait' }
            });
```

When I add width and height to the css part, the message area gets longer, but it doesn't happen again because it doesn't cover the whole page, and it looks ridiculous.

```
 $.blockUI({
                message: '<img src="/assets/media/loading3.gif" />',
                css: { height:'100%',width: '100%', border: '0px solid #FFFFFF', cursor: 'wait', backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' },
                overlayCSS: { backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', opacity: 0.0, cursor: 'wait' }
            });
```

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770299/jquery-blockui-transparent-loading-image